What are the structures of generated futures?
I just learned that we can use #[rustc_layout(debug)] to dump type layout from this blog post. And I immediately try to use it to see through generated futures.
Here's an example: (Rust Playground)
#![feature(rustc_attrs)]
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

use std::future::Future;
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::sync::{mpsc::UnboundedSender, oneshot::Receiver};

struct Actor {}

impl Actor {
    async fn act(&self, mut stop_listener: Receiver<()>, result_channel: UnboundedSender<u64>) {
        let part_1_jh = async {
            loop {
                if stop_listener.try_recv().is_ok() {
                    return;
                }
                println!("Hello from p1");
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(400)).await;
            }
        };

        let part_2_jh = async {
            loop {
                println!("Hello from p2");
                result_channel.send(43).unwrap();
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(700)).await;
            }
        };

        tokio::join!(part_1_jh, part_2_jh);
    }
}

#[rustc_layout(debug)]
type Fut<'a> = impl Future;

fn foo(this: &Actor, stop_listener: Receiver<()>, result_channel: UnboundedSender<u64>) -> Fut {
    this.act(stop_listener, result_channel)
}

And below is the dumped layout:
error: layout_of({async fn body of Actor::act()}) = Layout {
           size: Size(320 bytes),
           align: AbiAndPrefAlign {
               abi: Align(8 bytes),
               pref: Align(8 bytes),
           },
           abi: Aggregate {
               sized: true,
           },
           fields: Arbitrary {
               offsets: [
                   Size(296 bytes),
                   Size(272 bytes),
                   Size(304 bytes),
                   Size(313 bytes),
               ],
               memory_index: [
                   1,
                   0,
                   2,
                   3,
               ],
           },
           largest_niche: Some(
               Niche {
                   offset: Size(313 bytes),
                   value: Int(
                       I8,
                       false,
                   ),
                   valid_range: 0..=3,
               },
           ),
           variants: Multiple {
               tag: Initialized {
                   value: Int(
                       I8,
                       false,
                   ),
                   valid_range: 0..=3,
               },
               tag_encoding: Direct,
               tag_field: 3,
               variants: [
                   Layout {
                       size: Size(320 bytes),
                       align: AbiAndPrefAlign {
                           abi: Align(8 bytes),
                           pref: Align(8 bytes),
                       },
                       abi: Aggregate {
                           sized: true,
                       },
                       fields: Arbitrary {
                           offsets: [],
                           memory_index: [],
                       },
                       largest_niche: None,
                       variants: Single {
                           index: 0,
                       },
                       max_repr_align: None,
                       unadjusted_abi_align: Align(8 bytes),
                   },
                   Layout {
                       size: Size(320 bytes),
                       align: AbiAndPrefAlign {
                           abi: Align(8 bytes),
                           pref: Align(8 bytes),
                       },
                       abi: Aggregate {
                           sized: true,
                       },
                       fields: Arbitrary {
                           offsets: [],
                           memory_index: [],
                       },
                       largest_niche: None,
                       variants: Single {
                           index: 1,
                       },
                       max_repr_align: None,
                       unadjusted_abi_align: Align(8 bytes),
                   },
                   Layout {
                       size: Size(320 bytes),
                       align: AbiAndPrefAlign {
                           abi: Align(8 bytes),
                           pref: Align(8 bytes),
                       },
                       abi: Aggregate {
                           sized: true,
                       },
                       fields: Arbitrary {
                           offsets: [],
                           memory_index: [],
                       },
                       largest_niche: None,
                       variants: Single {
                           index: 2,
                       },
                       max_repr_align: None,
                       unadjusted_abi_align: Align(8 bytes),
                   },
                   Layout {
                       size: Size(320 bytes),
                       align: AbiAndPrefAlign {
                           abi: Align(8 bytes),
                           pref: Align(8 bytes),
                       },
                       abi: Aggregate {
                           sized: true,
                       },
                       fields: Arbitrary {
                           offsets: [
                               Size(280 bytes),
                               Size(288 bytes),
                               Size(0 bytes),
                               Size(256 bytes),
                               Size(312 bytes),
                           ],
                           memory_index: [
                               2,
                               3,
                               0,
                               1,
                               4,
                           ],
                       },
                       largest_niche: None,
                       variants: Single {
                           index: 3,
                       },
                       max_repr_align: None,
                       unadjusted_abi_align: Align(8 bytes),
                   },
               ],
           },
           max_repr_align: None,
           unadjusted_abi_align: Align(8 bytes),
       }

The layout has not only fields, but also variants. So I'm wondering what does it represent? Is it like a union of a struct that stores async fn arguments and an enum that stores async states?

Yes, a generated future type has variants corresponding to states of the future. As far as I know, it doesn't have any data outside of the variants. You can get more information about the type using -Zprint-type-sizes, particularly including names of the variants and (in some cases, by my own contribution) types of the fields. The first listed, and largest, type is act() itself:
type: `{async fn body of Actor::act()}`: 288 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    discriminant: 1 bytes
    variant `Unresumed`: 280 bytes
        padding: 239 bytes
        upvar `.stop_listener`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        padding: 16 bytes
        upvar `.self`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        upvar `.result_channel`: 8 bytes
    variant `Suspend0`: 281 bytes
        local `.futures`: 224 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        local `.__awaitee`: 16 bytes, type: tokio::future::poll_fn::PollFn<{closure@/Users/kpreid/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.37.0/src/macros/5:26}>
        upvar `.stop_listener`: 8 bytes
        local `.stop_listener`: 8 bytes
        local `.result_channel`: 8 bytes
        upvar `.self`: 8 bytes
        upvar `.result_channel`: 8 bytes
        local `..coroutine_field4`: 1 bytes, type: bool
    variant `Returned`: 280 bytes
        padding: 239 bytes
        upvar `.stop_listener`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        padding: 16 bytes
        upvar `.self`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        upvar `.result_channel`: 8 bytes
    variant `Panicked`: 280 bytes
        padding: 239 bytes
        upvar `.stop_listener`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        padding: 16 bytes
        upvar `.self`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        upvar `.result_channel`: 8 bytes
    end padding: 6 bytes

In this you can see that the initial state (Unresumed) has the captured variables, and the first and only Suspend* state must correspond to awaiting the implementation of tokio::join!. The Returned state is the state after the future has returned Poll::Ready. I don't know for sure what the Panicked state is used for, but presumably it is the state left behind when polling the future panics.
Notice that there's “padding” scattered throughout the variants; what's going on here is that the fields are arranged so that transitioning from one state to another doesn't require copying the data in the fields to new locations.
Further down the report you can find the inner async blocks:
type: `{async block@src/lib.rs:12:25: 20:10}`: 112 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    discriminant: 1 bytes
    variant `Unresumed`: 8 bytes
        upvar `._ref__stop_listener`: 8 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    variant `Suspend0`: 104 bytes
        upvar `._ref__stop_listener`: 8 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        local `.__awaitee`: 96 bytes, type: Sleep
    variant `Returned`: 8 bytes
        upvar `._ref__stop_listener`: 8 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    variant `Panicked`: 8 bytes
        upvar `._ref__stop_listener`: 8 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    end padding: 7 bytes
type: `{async block@src/lib.rs:22:25: 28:10}`: 112 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    discriminant: 1 bytes
    variant `Unresumed`: 8 bytes
        upvar `._ref__result_channel`: 8 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    variant `Suspend0`: 104 bytes
        upvar `._ref__result_channel`: 8 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
        local `.__awaitee`: 96 bytes, type: Sleep
    variant `Returned`: 8 bytes
        upvar `._ref__result_channel`: 8 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    variant `Panicked`: 8 bytes
        upvar `._ref__result_channel`: 8 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    end padding: 7 bytes

Again, each of these has only one await so they have only one Suspend state, awaiting a tokio::time::Sleep instance.
